# Override JSONSerializer on django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to apply this fix on my django rest framework
[Adding root element to json response (django-rest-framework)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824807/adding-root-element-to-json-response-django-rest-framework)

But I'm not sure how to override the json serializer on django rest framework, any help would be great.

The end result would be to have the root node name on the Json, because right now it's just an array of objects without the root name i.e.

not it looks like this

> [{"foo":"bar"}]

I would need it to be like this

> {"element": [{"foo":"bar"}]}

to get it to work with Ember JS

Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain briefly what you need to do..

Comment: hey @mariodev I edited the question to explain a bit better

Comment: The title should be "override JSONRenderer" instead of "override JSONSerializer"

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think you have your answer there in the post you've given.

You need to define custom JSON renderer

```
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer

class EmberJSONRenderer(JSONRenderer):

    def render(self, data, accepted_media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        data = {'element': data}
        return super(EmberJSONRenderer, self).render(data, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)
```

and use it as [default renderer](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers#setting-the-renderers) either in settings or as an explicitly defined render for you view, like:

```
class MyView(APIView):
    renderer_classes = (EmberJSONRenderer, )
    # ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, my only issue is that I'm not 100% sure where to add the custom code, and how to import it correctly, should I just add it on any file and then add the import to the view?

Comment: @user1713940 That depends on your project structure, you can create additional *utils* app and there create `renderers.py` and import your custom renderers from there.

Comment: Do you have any idea to change the name element according to the service? (e.g. for a service named ../foo/ your data will be  data = {'foo':data} but for other service called ../bar/ your data will be defined as data = {'bar':data} )

Answer (score 0):

```
def finalize_response(self, request, response, *args, **kwargs):
    response_code = response.status_code
    resp = Response(data=response.data, status=response_code)
    resp.accepted_renderer=request.accepted_renderer
    resp.accepted_media_type = request.accepted_media_type
    resp.renderer_context = self.get_renderer_context()
    return resp
 def get_renderer_context(self):
    """
    Returns a dict that is passed through to Renderer.render(),
    as the `renderer_context` keyword argument.
    """
    # Note: Additionally 'response' will also be added to the context,
    #       by the Response object.
    return {
        'view': self,
        'args': getattr(self, 'args', ()),
        'kwargs': getattr(self, 'kwargs', {}),
        'request': getattr(self, 'request', None)
    }
```