# Django REST Framework: Customize data dict on JSONRenderer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, renderer

I follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20424521/override-jsonserializer-on-django-rest-framework) which help me to know how override my JSONRenderer, but occurs me another doubt about How can I provide a arg to my overridden JSONRenderer so I can change my 'element' name as I want:

please take a look on the following snippet:

```
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer

class EmberJSONRenderer(JSONRenderer):

    def render(self, data, accepted_media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        data = {'element': data}
        return super(EmberJSONRenderer, self).render(data, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)
```

My intention is change this 'element' for a variable that i would like to get by arg for this reason I tried this :

in **renderers.py**

```
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer

class EmberJSONRenderer(JSONRenderer):
    def __init__(self,myarg='teste'):
        self.myarg = myarg

    def render(self, data, accepted_media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        data = {self.myarg:data}

        return super(EmberJSONRenderer, self).render(data, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)
```

in **views.py**:

```
class myViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    myrender = EmberJSONRenderer(myarg='abc')
    renderer_classes =  (myrender, BrowsableAPIRenderer, )
    queryset = mymodel.objects.filter(myfilter=2)
    serializer_class = mySerializer
    allowed_methods = ('GET','OPTIONS','HEAD')
```

this raise the following typeerror:

> 'EmberJSONRenderer' object is not callable

Do you have any suggestion how can i pass information from my view directly to renderer as arg?

Answer (score 4):

Hi everyone this was an approach that i found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824807/adding-root-element-to-json-response-django-rest-framework) and works for me. Instead of passing a var through my JSONRenderer i did the following:

in **serializer.py**:

```
class mySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        ...

  class Meta:
            model = ...
            service_name = 'mycustom name'
            fields = ...
```

than in my **renderer.py**:

```
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer

class EmberJSONRenderer(JSONRenderer):

    def render(self, data, accepted_media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
    service_name = getattr(renderer_context.get('view').get_serializer().Meta, 'service_name', 'objects')


        data = {service_name:{'name_pt':'name', 'keywords':data}}

        return super(EmberJSONRenderer, self).render(data, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)
```

as you can see i use the renderer_context to get information from view using `getattr` method:

```
getattr(renderer_context.get('view').get_serializer().Meta, 'service_name', 'objects')
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked for me, I needed to pass different functions for render method depending on the class.