# Django REST framework custom format for all out responses

Tags: python, angularjs, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

In my project I use DRF as backend and Angular as frontend.

Django==1.10
djangorestframework==3.7.1

I need all responses from DRF to be in the following format.

```
{
 "status": "",  //  200,400,.....etc
 "error": "",   //  True, False
 "data": [],    //  data
 "message": ""  //  Success messages
}
```

Currently it is in

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": ""
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": ""
    }
]
```

it should be

```
{
     "status": "200",   
     "error": "False",      
     "data": [
               {
                   "id": 1,
                   "name": ""
                },
                {
                   "id": 2,
                   "name": ""
                }
            ],    
     "message": "Success"  
}
```

for this i have written a custom viewset and overridden the functions list, detail, create, update

```
class ResponseModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        custom_data = {
            "status": True,
            "error": False,
            "message": 'message',
            "data": serializer.data
        }
        return Response(custom_data)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)

        custom_data = {
            "status": True,
            "error": False,
            "message": 'message',
            "data": serializer.data
        }

        return Response(custom_data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
        custom_data = {
            "status": True,
            "error": False,
            "message": 'message',
            "data": serializer.data
        }
        return Response(custom_data)

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=partial)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_update(serializer)

        if getattr(instance, '_prefetched_objects_cache', None):
            # If 'prefetch_related' has been applied to a queryset, we need to
            # forcibly invalidate the prefetch cache on the instance.
            instance._prefetched_objects_cache = {}

        custom_data = {
            "status": True,
            "error": False,
            "message": 'message',
            "data": serializer.data
        }
        return Response(custom_data)
```

and in views i use my custom viewset

```
from common.baseview import ResponseModelViewSet

class PositionViewsets(ResponseModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PositionSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    model = Position

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Position.objects.filter(order__user=self.request.user)
```

I am not sure if this is the correct way of doing it or there is some other efficient way to do it.
Anyway this works for my custom apps but not for the Authentication app
i used the default rest apps

```
'rest_framework.authtoken',
'rest_auth',
```

For login using username and password  and get  the success response as follows.

```
{
    "key": "e642efd0b78e08b57bf34fa999f49b70a7bfe21a"
}
```

Instead  i need this.

```
{
 "status": "200",   
 "error": "False",      
 "data": [
          {
           "token":{ 
                     "key":"e642efd0b78e08b57bf34fa999f49b70a7bfe21a"
                    }
           }
         ],     
 "message": "Login Sucess"  
}
```

for error

```
{
 "status": "error",     
 "error": "True",   
 "data": [
           {
            "email": ["Enter a valid email address."]
            }
         ],     
 "message": "Login Failed"  
}
```

Comment: You can override the behaviour of authtoken app's view class to inherit the base class you created.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some research I found a way to do this. I had to override the default behaviour of the `ModelViewSet` to output a different response.

I created a custom `Response` format initially:

```
class ResponseInfo(object):
    def __init__(self, user=None, **args):
        self.response = {
            "status": args.get('status', True),
            "error": args.get('error', 200),
            "data": args.get('data', []),
            "message": args.get('message', 'success')
        }
```

Then use this custom format in every method of the `ModelViewSet`:

```
class ResponseModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.response_format = ResponseInfo().response
        super(ResponseModelViewSet, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response_data = super(ResponseModelViewSet, self).list(request, *args, **kwargs)
        self.response_format["data"] = response_data.data
        self.response_format["status"] = True
        if not response_data.data:
            self.response_format["message"] = "List empty"
        return Response(self.response_format)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response_data = super(ResponseModelViewSet, self).create(request, *args, **kwargs)
        self.response_format["data"] = response_data.data
        self.response_format["status"] = True
        return Response(self.response_format)

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response_data = super(ResponseModelViewSet, self).retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
        self.response_format["data"] = response_data.data
        self.response_format["status"] = True
        if not response_data.data:
            self.response_format["message"] = "Empty"
        return Response(self.response_format)

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response_data = super(ResponseModelViewSet, self).update(request, *args, **kwargs)
        self.response_format["data"] = response_data.data
        self.response_format["status"] = True

        return Response(self.response_format)

    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response_data = super(ResponseModelViewSet, self).destroy(request, *args, **kwargs)
        self.response_format["data"] = response_data.data
        self.response_format["status"] = True
        return Response(self.response_format)
```

Comment: I was having the same question, but already solved with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20426493/3172310

Its uses a more general approach!

Maybe it helps

Answer (score 4):

This would be more a more robust solution, as it can be used with **Generic Views** hassle free.

Also, the checks in render() can be easily altered as per the needs (Eg., handling no-2XX in this solution).

```py
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer


class CustomRenderer(JSONRenderer):

    def render(self, data, accepted_media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        status_code = renderer_context['response'].status_code
        response = {
          "status": "success",
          "code": status_code,
          "data": data,
          "message": None
        }

        if not str(status_code).startswith('2'):
            response["status"] = "error"
            response["data"] = None
            try:
                response["message"] = data["detail"]
            except KeyError:
                response["data"] = data

        return super(CustomRenderer, self).render(response, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)
```