# How to use another serializer only for CREATE response?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am making a Shop management API. I will try to describe my problem shortly.

When I make a transaction, as a CREATE response I get,

```json
{
    "id": 14,
    "order": 1,
    "shop": 3,
    "product": 2,
    "quantity": 2,
    "bill": 600
}
```

But I would like to have a response with Product details like below.

```json
{
  "id": 14,
  "order": 1,
  "shop": 3,
  "product": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Product 2 for Shop 1",
    "buying_price": 200,
    "selling_price": 300,
    "stock": 34,
    "shop": 3
  },
  "quantity": 2,
  "bill": 600
}
```

So I **tried** to change the serializer when `self.action` is CREATE. But the problem is, now it's showing Product creating fields in my transaction.

**Models**

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    """Product model"""

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    buying_price = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    selling_price = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Transaction(models.Model):
    """Model for keeping customer ordered items"""

    order = models.ForeignKey(CustomerTrasnscation, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    bill = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

**ViewSet**

```py
class TransactionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    queryset = models.Transaction.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.TransactionSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        own_shop = getShop(self.request.user)
        serializer.save(shop=own_shop)

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action in ["list", "retrieve", "create"]:
            return serializers.Trasnscation_With_ProductDetailSerializer

        return self.serializer_class
```

**Problem**

As you can see, instead of showing Products name, it's showing Product creating fields.
[image: As you can see, instead of showing Products name, it's showing Product creating fields.]

**NOTE:** `Trasnscation_With_ProductDetailSerializer` is working absolutely fine on `list` and `retrieve` action.

Comment: Maybe these can help you: 1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20424521/override-jsonserializer-on-django-rest-framework/20426493#20426493   2) https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#setting-the-renderers

Answer (score 2):

You have to override your "create" method as your main serializer will `serializers.TransactionSerializer` but the response will be generated with `serializers.Trasnscation_With_ProductDetailSerializer`

```
def get_serializer_class(self):
    if self.action in ["list", "retrieve"]:
        return serializers.Trasnscation_With_ProductDetailSerializer

    return self.serializer_class

def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    obj = self.perform_create(serializer)

    serializer = serializers.Trasnscation_With_ProductDetailSerializer()(obj)

    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

Comment: @saifahmedanik if this answer works for you then please mark it as correct so others can also benefit from it, Thanks.