# Serializing one to many relationship using ModelSerializer

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I am aiming for a nested JSON response. My target output is like so;

```
[
 {
   list_id: <list_id_1>,
   list_name: <list_name_1>,
    {
       item_id: <item_id_1>,
       item_name: <item_name_1>,
    },
    {
       item_id: <item_id_2>,
       item_name: <item_name_2>,
    }
 }
]
```

I want to make my output to be a nested JSON. So far this is my progress;

models.py

```
class List(models.Model):
    list_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True, default='My List')

    def __str__(self):
        return ("List ID: " + str(self.id) + ", " + self.list_name)


class Item(models.Model):
    list = models.ForeignKey('List', related_name='items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False)
    item_desc = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    item_category = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    item_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, blank=False, null=False, default=0.00)
    item_qty = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False, default=1)
    is_complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return ("Item ID: " + str(self.id) + ", " + self.item_name)

    @property
    def item_tot_price(self):
        return (self.item_price * self.item_qty)
```

serializers.py

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    list_name = serializers.CharField(read_only=True, source = "list.list_name")

    class Meta:
        model = models.Item
        fields = ['id', 'list', 'list_name', 'item_name', 'item_desc', 'item_category', 'item_price', 'item_qty', 'is_complete', 'item_tot_price']
```

views.py

```
class ItemListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.ItemSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        This APIView should return a list of all the items 
        that are related to a List as determined by the 
        list portion of the URL.
        """
        list = self.kwargs['list']
        return models.Item.objects.filter(list__id=list)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('Items/<int:list>/', views.ItemListAPIView.as_view()),
]
```

The output using my current progress:

```
[
    {
        "item_id": 10,
        "list_id": 4,
        "list_name": "TestName",
        "item_name": "TestName",
        "item_desc": "TestName",
        "item_category": "TestName",
        "item_price": "2.00",
        "item_qty": 9,
        "is_complete": true,
        "item_tot_price": 18.0
    },
    {
        "item_id": 12,
        "list_id": 4,
        "list_name": "TestName",
        "item_name": "TestName",
        "item_desc": "TestName",
        "item_category": "TestName",
        "item_price": "0.00",
        "item_qty": 1,
        "is_complete": false,
        "item_tot_price": 0.0
    },
```

]

As you can see from my current output JSON, it sorts the items to the corresponding List. However I would like to display list_id and list_name as the parent, followed by the data for items.

In simple terms, I would like to make an endpoint that is able to GET the list_id and display all items that are related to the list.

Disclaimer: I've messed around with the serializer by using many=True agruments, related_fields, HyperlinkedModelSerializer. None of them worked the way I wanted.

Comment: You just can create a new Serializer e.g. "ListSerializer" which gets constructed just the way you did with the ItemSerializer. The "ListSerializer" contains the ItemSerializer with many=True. Perhaps you can try this and post your solution. If it does not help, just ask again.

Comment: My mistake. Before this I made ItemSerializer and put many=True for List. From my understanding, there are many records of items, so I immediately thought it would display all of the items in that list assuming I made a custom get_queryset. It would seem I got it wrong. Thank you for pointing it out. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your `serializers.py` like below. Instead of serializing `Item`, use `List` so in your `views.py` you will use `ListSerializer` instead of `ItemSerializer`

```py
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    list_name = serializers.CharField(read_only=True, source = "list.list_name")

    class Meta:
        model = models.Item
        fields = ['id', 'list', 'list_name', 'item_name', 'item_desc', 'item_category', 'item_price', 'item_qty', 'is_complete', 'item_tot_price']

class ListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    items = ItemSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = List
        fields = ['id','list_name','items']
```

Comment: Just curious since I am still playing around with the serializer and view. Is it possible if I want to put the name "Lists" at the top of the nested JSON response? Like so;

[
 "Lists": 
    {
        "id": 7,
        "list_name": "list_name",
        "items": [
            {
                "id": 18,     
            },

Comment: My frontend dev wants to know if it is possible to add the name "Lists" at the start of the JSON response.

Comment: I think this is what you want -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20424521/override-jsonserializer-on-django-rest-framework

Comment: exactly what I needed. I've been wondering what was the purpose of renderers this whole time. Now I know how crucial it is when making an API. This way I can manipulate. Thanks again. Cheers mate.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Yves Hary & @adnan kaya,

From what Yves said, I modified my ListSerializer to include

```
items = ItemSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
```

Hence,

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    list_name = serializers.CharField(read_only=True, source = "list.list_name")

    class Meta:
        model = models.Item
        fields = ['id', 'list', 'list_name', 'item_name', 'item_desc', 'item_category', 'item_price', 'item_qty', 'is_complete', 'item_tot_price']


class ListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """New Line Added Here"""
    items = ItemSerializer(many=True, read_only=True) 

    class Meta:
        model = models.List
        fields = ['id', 'list_name', 'items']
```

I made the adjustments earlier and based on the answer given by adnan, it confirms it that the method is correct.

With this current serializer, if I use a ModelViewSet, it will display all list with all of its items. Like so;

```
class ListViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.List.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ListSerializer
```

My aim was to display specific list with its items. So, I implemented a view using generics.ListAPIView like so;

```
class ListItemAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.ListSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        list = self.kwargs['list']
        return models.List.objects.filter(id=list)
```

Finally, my urls.py looks like this;

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('List/<int:list>/', views.ListItemAPIView.as_view()),
]
```

Only then my output will be like this;

```
[
    {
        "list_id": <list_id>,
        "list_name": "<list_name>",
        "items": [
            {
                "item_id": <item_id>,
                "list_id": <list_id>,
                "list_name": "<list_name>",
                "item_name": "TestName",
                "item_desc": "TestName",
                "item_category": "TestName",
                "item_price": "2.00",
                "item_qty": 3,
                "is_complete": false,
                "item_tot_price": 6.0
            },
            {
                "item_id": <item_id>,
                "list_id": <list_id>,
                "list_name": "<list_name>",
                "item_name": "TestName",
                "item_desc": "TestName",
                "item_category": "TestName",
                "item_price": "2.00",
                "item_qty": 3,
                "is_complete": false,
                "item_tot_price": 6.0
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

EDIT: Encapsulate the JSON response and added the keyword "lists";

renderers.py

```
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer, BrowsableAPIRenderer


class BaseFlutterJSONRenderer(JSONRenderer):

    def render(self, data, accepted_media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        data = {'lists': data}
        return super(BaseFlutterJSONRenderer, self).render(data, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)


class FlutterJSONRenderer(BrowsableAPIRenderer):
    def get_default_renderer(self, view):
        return BaseFlutterJSONRenderer()
```

Comment: Note 1: I will clean up the ItemSerializer so that it will not display too many redundant data.

Note 2: Special thanks to both @Yves Hary&adnan kaya

Comment: You are welcome **if the answer was useful you can accept it.**