# django rest framework - custom renderer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to tweak the existing XMLRenderer to create a custom one -

```
class CustomRenderer(renderers.BaseRenderer):
    """
    Renderer which serializes to CustomXML.
    """

    media_type = 'application/xml'
    format = 'xml'
    charset = 'utf-8'

    def render(self, data, accepted_media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        """
        Renders *obj* into serialized XML.
        """
        if data is None:
            return ''

        stream = StringIO()

        xml = SimplerXMLGenerator(stream, self.charset)
        xml.startDocument()
        xml.startElement("job id='string1'", {})

        self._to_xml(xml, data)

        xml.endElement("job")
        xml.endDocument()
        return stream.getvalue()

    def _to_xml(self, xml, data):
        if isinstance(data, (list, tuple)):
            for item in data:
                xml.startElement("string2", {})
                self._to_xml(xml, item)
                xml.endElement("string2")

        elif isinstance(data, dict):
            for key, value in six.iteritems(data):
                xml.startElement(key, {})
                self._to_xml(xml, value)
                xml.endElement(key)

        elif data is None:
            # Don't output any value
            pass

        else:
            xml.characters(smart_text(data))
```

For string1 I want it to get the value from the view that's calling it.  string1 = the primary key from the GET in the API.

ie. if I'm calling `http://localhost/API/2345 then string1 = 2345`

For string2 I want it to return the model name similar to what they are doing in the following post -

[Adding root element to json response (django-rest-framework)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824807/adding-root-element-to-json-response-django-rest-framework)

Which is customizing the values returned by the Renderer so that the root value of the JSON/XML can be set as the model name.

I've tried tweaking the CustomRenderer to contain the lines but then when running my view it complains that "object() takes no parameters" on my views.py -

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    DEV = Trgjob.objects.using('database1').filter(job_id=pk).order_by('job_order')
    serializer = CustomSerializer(DEV, many=True)
    return CustomRenderer(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Please explain your questions better. `string1 = pk` what is `pk`? Also describe the second question here instead of pointing us to another url..

Comment: updated to explain a bit better.

Comment: please follow this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/73497128/4939915

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to return the renderer instance from the view?
You should just be returning regular data from the view, but set the renderer classes using the `renderer_classes` attribute on the view class.

```
class MyView(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [CustomRenderer]

    ...

    def get(self, request, pk=None):
        DEV = Trgjob.objects.using('database1').filter(job_id=pk).order_by('job_order')
        serializer = CustomSerializer(DEV, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**Edit**:  As to getting extra context into the renderer from the view... you can do that by inspecting `renderer_context['view']`, so something along these lines in your `render()` method...

```
view = renderer_context['view']
job_id = view.kwargs['job_id']
```

Comment: I'm confused this isn't mentioning anywhere how I would parse that "string1" in.  I have my serializer, renderer and view working great.  What's happening is I want to parse in another variable from the view to pass into the renderer so when it's calling "CustomRenderer" it can also know that string1 = "xxxx" of which I want to define string1 = "xxxx" in my view.

Comment: @whoisearth - Updated with some more info on that.

Comment: I think I'm understanding where you're coming from I'm trying to figure out how to make it work in my view.  The problem is the examples in the django-rest-framework documentation aren't actually showing an example of using this renderer_context.

In the custom renderer I copied and tweaked it has the renderer_context in there could I not just use that or because it's separate files it needs to be used directly in the view?