# How to serialize a dictionary containing lists with Django-Restframework?

Tags: json, django, list, django-rest-framework

I'm creating a REST-API for my Django-App. I have a function, that returns a list of dictionaries, that I would like to serialize and return with the rest-api.

The list (nodes_of_graph) looks like this:
[{'id': 50, position: {'x': 99.0, 'y': 234.0}, 'locked': True}, {'id': 62, position: {'x': 27.0, 'y': 162.0}, 'locked': True}, {'id': 64, position: {'x': 27.0, 'y': 162.0}, 'locked': True}]

Since I'm a rookie to python, django and the Restframwork, I have no clue how to attempt this. Is anybody here, who knows how to tackle that?

somehow all my attempts to serialize this list have failed. I've tried with

```py
class Graph_Node_Serializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    class Nodes: 
        fields = (
            'id',
            'position',
            'locked',
        )

def nodes_for_graph(request, id): 
    serializer = Graph_Node_Serializer(nodes_of_graph)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

The result I hope for is an response of the django-rest-framwork, containing the data in the list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use multiple objects in your serializer, you need to put the `many=True` parameter. Besides, you need to use `Serializer` instead of `ListSerializer` such as:

```py
class Graph_Node_Serializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Nodes: 
        fields = (
            'id',
            'position',
            'locked',
        )

def nodes_for_graph(request, id): 
    serializer = Graph_Node_Serializer(nodes_of_graph, many=True)
    response = JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
```

Comment: Thanks, Cagrias! It looks much better. 

Still, now I get the error-response 'child is a required argument', what is wrong? looking forward for a nice and handy solution! :D

Comment: Thanks––slowly but surely are we getting there! I've implemented your code fragement, and made some changes by my own: 

I've changed response to Jsonresponse(serializer.data, safe=True). 

Now, the json-File has the right amount of objects in the list, but the dictionaries are all empty. Why that? Because of the dictionary in the dictionary?

Comment: I'll get the error message: 
«.accepted_renderer not set on Response». 

When I tag the function with the mark «@api_view()» i'll get the rest-scree, with the empty brackets.

Comment: Ok try my updated answer, I've used `JsonResponse` to return.

Comment: Hmm, like that I get «didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead».

Comment: Ok I think thats happening because of your custom fields. Follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/46328281/4665915 this answer and override `to_representation`.

Comment: Thanks alot for your thought. Even if they aren't the solution, they've brought me to a feasable one.

Answer (score 0):

A Solution that works is to create a sub-class of the Serializer-class. For the problem formulated here, it would look like this:

```
Graph_Node_Serializer(serializers.Serializer)
    id = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    class PositionSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
        x = serializers.FloatField(required=True)
        y = serializers.FloatField(required=True)
    position = PositionSerializer(required=False)
    locked = serializers.BooleanField(required=False, default=True)

def nodes_for_graph(request, graph_id): 
    serializer = Graph_Node_Serializer(nodes_of_graph, many=True)
    Response(serializer.data)
```