# Where to alter the response of POST request in Django REST Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a view which inherit from `CreateAPIView` with a model serializer set up in Django REST framework.

When I send a request, it returns a JSON representation of the object that was created.

I would like to wrap the data from the response as shown below:

```
{'data'   : { 'field1' : 'value1' ,
              'field2' : value2 , 
               etc.....
             } , 
 'errors' : None , 
 'message': [{} , {}] , 
 'result' : 'OK' , 
}
```

Where is the best place to modify the data that gets returned?

I tried to create a custom renderer as was shown in this question: [Adding root element to json response (django-rest-framework)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824807/adding-root-element-to-json-response-django-rest-framework#14885270) but it never gets called. 
Is that because it is only relevant for GET requests rather than posts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that this structure is not very relevant :

1. **result** : why include a field to say `OK` since the status code of the request is here to give you this information : 200 -> OK, 201 -> created, 400 -> bad request, etc...
2. **data** and **errors** in the same response doesn't make sense to me. Maybe, you got a special behavior in `created` method of your serializer but if there is an error, it seems logic that there is no data to send back (maybe I'm wrong). DRF allow you to validate data with `.is_valid()` method, and you can simply send back errors with (for example)

```python
return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

or directly raise exception with `.is_valid(raise_exception=True)`.

Nevertheless, if you wanna keep this structure, this job can be done in your view. Example :

```python
return Response({
    'data': serializer.data,
    'errors': serializer.errors, # `.is_valid()` must be called
    'message': [{} , {}], 
    'result':'OK'
})
```

Comment: I kind of agree but thats what I was asked to implement.

Comment: oh ok. So as I said, do this job in your view. If you use a lot of time this structure, you can create an helper function to build this structure depending on the serializer passed. :)

Comment: Its talking to Salesforce, which is horrible to work with all round. Everything takes way more effort than it should.

Comment: Yeah, I guessed that this structure was imposed by an API :D