# Django rest framework how to return data field and success field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I using Django rest framework,and I hava a question:

my model:

```
class Store_Rotation(models.Model):
    store = models.ForeignKey(Stores)
    rotation = models.ImageField(upload_to='rotation/', verbose_name="轮播图")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.rotation.url
```

my serializer:

```
class Store_RotationSerializer(ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = Store_Rotation
    fields = '__all__'
```

my view:

```
class Store_RotationViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Store_Rotation.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Store_RotationSerializer
```

It return this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "rotation": "http://192.168.33.10:8000/files/rotation/%E4%B8%9A%E5%8A%A1%E6%B5%81%E7%A8%8B%E5%9B%BE.png",
        "store": 1
    }
]
```

I want to return this:

```
{
data:
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "rotation": "http://192.168.33.10:8000/files/rotation/%E4%B8%9A%E5%8A%A1%E6%B5%81%E7%A8%8B%E5%9B%BE.png",
            "store": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

How to do this?
It have some general method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will have to override the to_representation method on your list serializer class

define a list serializer class:

```
class StoreRotationListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):

    def to_representation(self, data):
        repr = super(StoreRotationListSerializer, self).to_representation(data)
        return {'data': repr}
```

now use this list serializer class in your main serializer:

```
class Store_RotationSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Store_Rotation
        fields = '__all__'
        list_serializer_class = StoreRotationListSerializer
```

read more about list serializer here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#listserializer

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom renderer and assign that if you want to use it often. Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16829132/1233686). Otherwise you can return a [Response](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses/) manually by overriding the corresponding [viewset](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/) function.